# HTML Form Parse Checked Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have some checkbox Code:

```
echo "<td>"
    echo "<input type = \"checkbox\" name=\"name\" value=\"$name\">";
    echo "<input type = \"hidden\" name=\"user\" value=\"$user\">"; 
echo "</td>"
```

The code above represents **one** check box so each checkbox has multiple name/value pairs. Imagine I have a ton of these checkboxes. I want to find every checked checkbox and then print out each of the name/value pairs for the checkbox.

Here is my code so far:

```
var formData = {};
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    $(this).find("input[name]").each(function(index, node){
        formData[node.name] = node.value;
        alert (node.name + node.value);
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your each function like the following:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {         
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $(this).find("input[name]").each(function(index, node){
            console.log('a');
            formData[node.name] = node.value;
            alert (node.name + node.value);
        });
        }
    });
```

This is beacuse initially your checkboxes are not in checked state. So you need to track the checked/unchecked event to make it work. Hope it helps.